# Converting ISO8601 duration (P3Y6M...) to seconds in perl

Tags: perl, iso8601

I'm trying to convert an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) time duration format, P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S, to seconds in perl. Is there a library that does this? I've tried searching, but I've only found a js library. Looking through DateTime and Time::Moment didn't provide a solution either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [DateTime::Format::Duration::ISO8601](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration::ISO8601), which can convert the ISO 8601 duration string into a [DateTime::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration) object. You can then convert that to seconds.

```
use DateTime::Duration;
use DateTime::Format::Duration::ISO8601;

my $format = DateTime::Format::Duration::ISO8601->new;
my $d = $format->parse_duration('P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S');
```

However, the DateTime::Duration format cannot be used to convert a year to seconds, as explained [in the docs here](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration#$dur-%3Ein_units(-...-)).

> The last example demonstrates that there will not be any conversion
>   between units which don't have a fixed conversion rate. The only
>   conversions possible are:
>
> ```
> years <=> months
> weeks <=> days
> hours <=> minutes
> seconds <=> nanoseconds
> ```
>
> For the explanation of why this is the case, please see the [How
>   DateTime Math Works](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#How-DateTime-Math-Works) section of the DateTime.pm documentation

You can use [DateTime::Format::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration) with the `%s` [pattern](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration#Patterns) to circumvent that. A complete implementation might look like this.

```
use DateTime::Duration;
use DateTime::Format::Duration::ISO8601;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

my $format = DateTime::Format::Duration::ISO8601->new;
my $d      = $format->parse_duration('P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S');

my $output_format = DateTime::Format::Duration->new( pattern => '%s' );
print $output_format->format_duration($d);
```

Or, in short if you only need it once.

```
use DateTime::Duration;
use DateTime::Format::Duration::ISO8601;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

print DateTime::Format::Duration->new( pattern => '%s' )
    ->format_duration(
    DateTime::Format::Duration::ISO8601->new->parse_duration('P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S') );
```

Both of these will print

```
109254605
```

Comment: Re "*However, the DateTime::Duration format cannot be used to convert a year to seconds*", It can; just not easily. This should do it: `my $dt1 = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => 0, time_zone => 'floating'); my $dt2 = $dt1->clone->add_duration($dur); my $secs = $dt2->delta_ms($dt1)->in_units('seconds');`